# Profile specific application-{profile}.yaml file is not loading in spring boot 2.4.1

Tags: spring, spring-boot, profile, spring-profiles, spring-properties

In my project their is a bootstrap.yml file in which they set the spring.profiles.active as 'dev' and i have application-dev.yaml file in the resource folder. when I run the application the bootstrap.yaml file is loaded and set the profile as 'dev'. I am able to see that in the log as **The following profiles are active: dev** but the application-dev.yaml is not loaded. I am using spring boot 2.4.1.release.

Please see the code below:

### bootstrap.yml:

spring:
application:
name: eureka-server
profiles:
active: dev
cloud:
config:
uri: http://localhost:8080/
enabled: TRUE
name: eureka-server

### application-dev.yaml:

server:
port: 8081

spring:
application:
name: eureka-service

if the application load application-dev.yaml then tomcat should use the port as 8081 but tomcat use the default port as 8080. please see the log below.

[log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuePz.png)

Please let me know why the application-dev.yaml file is not loaded even if the active profile is set as 'dev'.

When I rename the application-dev.yaml as application.yaml and then removed the active.profile:dev from bootstrap.yaml file then the application load the config and tomcat use the port as 8081.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots to show logs